# View how many Google Adwords PLA spend versus text

Tags: google-ads-api

I need to figure out how I can view how many Google Adwords PLA I spent versus text ads. Where in reporting on in Adwords can I do this?

Comment: Product Listing Ads are now Shopping Ads and you'll find them under Aquisition/Adwords/Shopping Ads. Not exactly on topic, though.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you know how I can compare how many shopping ads I spent versus text?